# iptables Rules show in textView in android;

Tags: android, textview, runtime, execution, iptables

i want to show the rules i've created in a textView, using this code;

..................................

```
                  public void show(View btn) throws IOException{

                 Show(tv);
                   }


        public final void Show(TextView tv) throws IOException{
            Process Q =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c iptables -L INPUT 1 -n -v --line-numbers ");


             String pingResult="";
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(Q.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

                           tv.setText(pingResult+="\n"+inputLine+"\n");

                    }
                    in.close();
                                        } 
                                }
```

the problem is that it tells me superuser permission granted, but the table doesn't appear in the TextView, even though i've used BufferReader ..... help ?

Answer (score 0):

With this code portion Im doing the same you need but listing a directory and reading the input. Try using this code changing the getRuntime().exec Command.

```
private String[] GetAppFiles() throws IOException
    {
        int BUFF_LEN =2048;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "system/bin/sh"});
        DataOutputStream stdin = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        //from here all commands are executed with su permissions
        stdin.writeBytes("ls " + CurrentApkPath + "\n"); // \n executes the command
        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_LEN];
        int read;
        String out = new String();
        //read method will wait forever if there is nothing in the stream
        //so we need to read it in another way than while((read=stdout.read(buffer))>0)
        while(true){
            read = stdout.read(buffer);
            out += new String(buffer, 0, read);
            if(read<BUFF_LEN){
                //we have read everything
                break;
            }
        }
```

I hope it helps you.